# Are the "Lord of the Rings" and "The Hobbit" movies connected someway?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit

Are those two movies connected, if yes, what should be the order in which I shall watch these movies?

Comment: They are in the same universe, but they don't need really an order. The Hobbit is supposed to happen before the Lord of The Rings, and it wasn't filmed/released in that order. No issue there.

Answer (score 2):

The Hobbit is the prequel to the Lord Of The Rings trilogy.  It's during his exploits chronicled in the Hobbit book (movie) that Bilbo first finds the One Ring, and the Lord Of The Rings trilogy is all about Bilbo needing to get said ring to Mordor to be destroyed.  Of course, his nephew Frodo is actually tasked with the delivery, but Bilbo does meet up with him in Rivendell.